Quiero que al escribir un valor en un campo de html y que vaya a la base de datos MySql a ver si existe y si es afirmativo que me cargue informacion
Estoy haciendo una web con php y html que realiza consultas a la base de datos Mysql. Tengo un formulario en html y cuando escribo el campo del cif quiero que me consulte si existe en la base de datos mysql y si es así que me devuelva los valores de otros campos que tengo en el formulario.
Mi código del archivo registro.php del formulario es el siguiente:
<?php
        session_start();
        include "../conexion.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php include "includes/scripts3.php"; ?>
    <title>Registro práctica</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>

    <section id="container">
        <div class"title_page">
            <h1><i class="fas fa-cube"></i> Nueva práctica</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_empresa">
            <div class="action_empresa">
                <h4>Datos de la empresa</h4>
                <a href="#" class="btn_new btn_new_empresa"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Nueva empresa</a>
            </div>
            <form name="form_new_empresa_practicas" id="form_new_empresa_practicas" class="datos">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addEmpresa">
                <input type="hidden" id="idempresa" name="idempresa" value="" required>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>CIF empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cif_empresa" id="cif_empresa">
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Nombre empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nom_empresa" id="nom_empresa" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Dirección empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dir_empresa" id="dir_empresa" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Localidad empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" name="loc_empresa" id="loc_empresa" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Código postal empresa</label>
                    <input type="number" name="cp_empresa" id="cp_empresa" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Provincia empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pro_empresa" id="pro_empresa" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Teléfono empresa</label>
                    <input type="number" name="tel_empresa" id="tel_empresa" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div id="div_registro_empresa" class="wd100">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn_save"><i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i> Crear empresa</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </section>

    <?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>

El código del archivo ajax.php donde realizo la búsqueda en la base de datos es el siguiente:
<?php

    include "../conexion.php";
    session_start();

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        // Buscar empresa
        if($_POST['action'] == 'searchEmpresa')
        {
            if(!empty($_POST['empresa'])){

                $cif = $_POST['empresa'];
                $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE cif LIKE '$cif' and estatus=1");
                mysqli_close($conection);
                $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                $data = '';
                if($result > 0){
                    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                }else{
                    $data = 0;
                }
                echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            }
            exit;
        }


    }

    exit;
?>

Tengo un archivo functions.js donde realizo las funciones que necesito y su código es este:
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Activa campos para registrar empresa

    $('.btn_new_empresa').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nom_empresa').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#dir_empresa').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#loc_empresa').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#cp_empresa').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#pro_empresa').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#tel_empresa').removeAttr('disabled');

        $('#div_registro_empresa').slideDown();
    });


    Buscar empresa
    $('#cif_empresa').keyup(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var emp = $(this).val();
        var action = 'searchEmpresa';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            async : true,
            data: {action:action,empresa:emp},

            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);

                if(reponse == 0){
                    $('#idempresa').val('');
                    $('#nom_empresa').val('');
                    $('#dir_empresa').val('');
                    $('#loc_empresa').val('');
                    $('#cp_empresa').val('');
                    $('#pro_empresa').val('');
                    $('#tel_empresa').val('');

                    $('.btn_new_empresa').slideDown();
                }else{
                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $('#idempresa').val(data.idempresa);
                    $('#nom_empresa').val(data.empresa);
                    $('#dir_empresa').val(data.direccion);
                    $('#loc_empresa').val(data.localidad);
                    $('#cp_empresa').val(data.cp);
                    $('#pro_empresa').val(data.provincia);
                    $('#tel_empresa').val(data.telefono);

                    $('btn_new_empresa').slideUp();

                    // Bloque campos desactivados
                    $('#nom_empresa').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#dir_empresa').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#loc_empresa').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#cp_empresa').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#pro_empresa').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#tel_empresa').attr('disabled','disabled');

                    $('#div_registro_empresa').slideUp();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {

            }
        });
    });


}); // End Ready

La conexión a la base de datos la realiza correctamente y el archivo conexion.php es este:
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'aula';

    // Intenta establecer la conexión a la base de datos
    $conection = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

    // Verifica si hay errores de conexión
    if(!$conection){
        echo "Error en la conexión";
    }

?>

He hecho formularios de registro sobre la base de datos y funcionan sin problemas, pero este que tiene que consultar y cargar datos desde la base de datos no sé porque no funciona. Llevo 2 días dando vueltas y no encuentro el motivo.
Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.
Un saludo

la busqueda debe ser exacta o puede ser si contiene la busqueda... creo que esto '$cif' deberia ser esto '%$cif%', el simbolo de % ayuda a buscar cualquier cosa que se paresca...

Aparte de lo que te comenta @FranciscoNuñezIALover, ¿podrías explicar por qué lanzas la petición Ajax basándote en keyup? Me refiero a esto: $('#cif_empresa').keyup(function(e){. Al usar keyup se lanzará una búsqueda por cada tecla que vayas presionando. ¿Acaso quieres algo como una búsqueda predictiva? En la parte del success no parece ser eso lo deseado, si no encontrar una empresa en específico. Me refiero a esta parte: $('#idempresa').val(data.idempresa);

He añadido el símbolo % pero sigue sin funcionar.

Respecto a la petición usando keyup, lo utilizo para que cada vez que teclee algo lance la búsqueda, por eso luego añado e.preventDefault(); para que no recargue tras cada búsqueda.  Si quiero encontrar una empresa especifica que tenga el cif concreto, pero cuando pongo un cif completo que existe, no carga.

Cuando me encuentro en estos casos raros, lo que hago es retornan la query -> echo json_encode($query), si me retorna algo ya sé que por lo menos se está ejecutando, luego pruebo esa query directamente en la bd para cerciorarme que he formado una query correcta

keyup tendría sentido si necesitaras una búsqueda predictiva,  por ejemplo cuando empiezas a escribir caracteres y se van mostrando debajo todas las palabras que empiezan por esos caracteres. No parece ser eso lo que requieres aquí, sino UNA empresa que empiece por un determinado CIF. Pusa UNA en mayúscula porque en tu código no se contempla ninguna posibilidad de mostrar más de un resultado. Insisto en esto porque muchas veces el problema es sobre todo de enfoque. Me parece que no queda claro qué es lo que quieres lograr con este código. Que funcione o no es lo de menos aquí.

no uses key up.. usa un timer que ejecute un segundo despues de que escriba la ultima letra.. y explica las mil funciones que pusiste...

Hola Frami, la petición devuelve error? Que significa  que no funciona? Has verificado que json_encode no falle y devuelva false?

Hola, encontré el problema!! tenia un problema en el js que hacia que no ejecutara el jquery. Una vez he resuelto el problema y he visto que en consola ya realizaba consultas, ya he podido continuar y por fin me devuelve la información de la base de datos.

Gracias a todos por vuestros comentarios.
